# how to use Loop in c# insert query

Tags: c#, mysql, loops

i'm a student in a vocational highschool and a newbie  programmer..
i have some problem with using loop in my insert query..
i have  two table, Book and Book_detail, wich link with foreign key, and i want to save data to both table, and the problem is every time i add a book, i have  a textbox named copies_txt, the idea is i want to save the same book_id and the same location_id in the book_detail table but with diffrent boookdetail_id as much as the amount i insert in copies_txt.. and to achieve that i try  using for loop, but i gives me error

> duplicate entry for key Primary

, here's my full code

```
int copies = Convert.ToInt32(copies_txt.Text);                      
        int i;


        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "insert into simbada_perpustakaan.book(book_id,title,release_date,genre,author,copies,create_by,create_date) values ('" + this.book_id.Text + "','" + this.title_txt.Text + "','" + this.time.Text + "','" + this.genre_txt.Text + "','" + this.author_txt.Text + "','" + this.copies_txt.Text + "','" + this.username_lbl.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "') ; ";
        string Query2 = "insert into simbada_perpustakaan.book_detail(id_bookdetail,book_id,location_id) values('" + Guid.NewGuid() + "','" + this.book_id.Text + "','" + this.textBox1.Text + "') on duplicate key update id_bookdetail=(id_bookdetail=('"+Guid.NewGuid()+"'))";            
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase2 = new MySqlCommand(Query2, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            conDataBase.Close();                
            for (i = 0; i <= copies; i++)
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDataBase2.ExecuteReader();
                conDataBase.Close();              

            }              
            MessageBox.Show("saved"); 
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

can somebody please point out my mistake...  thanks before.

Comment: inside the loop you are inserting query 2 multiple times. and its first value is Guid.NewGuid() which will be a primary key and you are assinging it outside loop.So always same value..so it will violate the primary key rule\

Comment: oh... ok, thx, and if it's not too much to ask, can you give some solution for that matter?

Comment: before that tell me if same GUID exist in the second table what do you want to do? bcos in the second query i can see `on duplicate`

Comment: well, i  dont know if it's the  righ query for that  matter, but here's the goal... if the GUID already exist in the book_detail table i want the  system to create new GUID and continue to insert the next value...

Comment: ok understand then you should place the query inside the loop

Comment: ho can i corretly move the query inside the loop? i try to change the query and i try to move it inside the loop but it gives me more error mssg...sry if i ask too much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79238/discussion-between-sachu-and-joshua-egberio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is with the second query. Move the query inside the loop and check. Also you don't need a data reader since it's a select statement. Also you can avoid multiple database open and close statement. Try below code

```
int copies = Convert.ToInt32(copies_txt.Text);                      
        int i;
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "insert into simbada_perpustakaan.book(book_id,title,release_date,genre,author,copies,create_by,create_date) values ('" + this.book_id.Text + "','" + this.title_txt.Text + "','" + this.time.Text + "','" + this.genre_txt.Text + "','" + this.author_txt.Text + "','" + this.copies_txt.Text + "','" + this.username_lbl.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd/hh/mm/ss") + "') ; ";

        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
           cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonquery();

            for (i = 0; i <= copies; i++)
            {

              string a = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
              string Query2 = "insert into simbada_perpustakaan.book_detail(id_bookdetail,book_id,location_id) values('" + a + "','" + this.book_id.Text + "','" + this.textBox1.Text + "') on duplicate key update id_bookdetail=(id_bookdetail=('"+a+"'))"; 
               MySqlCommand cmdDataBase2 = new MySqlCommand(Query2, conDataBase);
               cmdDataBase2.ExecuteNonQuery();


            }              
            MessageBox.Show("saved"); 
            conDataBase.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Also always try to do parameterized query. That can avoid sql injection problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let,

```
first Guid.NewGuid() = 'zxcvbnm'

second Giud.NewGuid() = 'asdfghjkl'

book_id = 2

location_id = 3
```

After executing Query2 we get the string like

```
insert into book_detail(id_bookdetail,book_id,location_id) values('zxcvbnm','2'
,'3') on duplicate key update id_bookdetail='asdfghjkl';
```

when we try to execute it at for loop then

```
When i = 0
```

It inserts data fine as `id_bookdetail('zxcvbnm') is unique.`

```
When i = 1
```

It also inserts data fine because `id_bookdetail('zxcvbnm')` is used ago but using on duplicate key id_bookdetail set `a new value('asdfghjkl')` which is unique.

```
But When i = 2
```

It gives you error because first he gets `id_bookdetaidid('zxvbnm')` as duplicate, then he try to use `second one('asdfghjkl')` which is also duplicate. So it gives you that error.

Comment: `If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed`..correct me if iam wrong

Comment: @Sachu, It doesn't update any previous row. It inserts first 2 then it gives `duplicate key` error.